# Host key verification failed. fatal: Could not read from remote repository. GitHub Pages

Tags: node.js, git, npm

I am getting the error below when using "npm run deploy". This repo was cloned using https.

UPDATE: It seems to be working after this quick revision of the remote set-url. The repo wasn't cloned using the SSH option so the remote set-url required the appropriate "https://" instead. Have a great day!

I changed the "git remote set-url origin git@github.com!laurenwatkins!laurenwatkins.github.io"

to git remote set-url origin https://github.com/laurenwatkins/laurenwatkins.github.io.git

```
> saadpasta.github.io@0.1.0 deploy C:\Users\laurenwatkins\Software\developerFolio
> gh-pages -b master -d build

Cloning into 'node_modules\gh-pages\.cache\git@github.com!laurenwatkins!laurenwatkins.github.io'...
Host key verification failed.
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.

npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! saadpasta.github.io@0.1.0 deploy: `gh-pages -b master -d build`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the saadpasta.github.io@0.1.0 deploy script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\laurenwatkins\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2020-02-13T11_07_18_464Z-debug.log
```

Comment: did you tried looking into a logfile from last line of your post?

Comment: @zed_0xff Yes. I do not see anything in there of note for revision.

Comment: @zed_0xff any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

UPDATE: It seems to be working after this quick revision of the remote set-url. The repo wasn't cloned using the SSH option so the remote set-url required the appropriate "https://" instead. Have a great day!

The following "git remote set-url origin was changed.

Previous URL(error): git@github.com!laurenwatkins!laurenwatkins.github.io"

Updated URL(working): git remote set-url origin https://github.com/laurenwatkins/laurenwatkins.github.io.git